# How to free the pointer to int, which then becomes the pointer to the result of the function?

Tags: c, pointers

I have an pointer to int:

```
   int* convex = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
   if(convex == NULL) {
       free(convex);
       return 0;
   }
```

then I do smth like this:

```
convex = check_figure(x_points, y_points);
```

function was declared:

```
int* check_figure(float* x_points[], float* y_points[]);
```

then I do:

```
free(convex);

for( i = 0; i < n+1; i++) {
    free(x_points[i]);
    free(y_points[i]);
}

free(x_points);
free(y_points);
```

why does valgrind say that I haven't free the memory for variable:convex ?

---

it's ok with arrays, because I do like this:

```
x_points = (float**)malloc(sizeof(float*) * (n+1));


y_points = (float**)malloc(sizeof(float*) * (n+1));
```

Comment: Why in your first code sample are you calling `free` on a `NULL` pointer? That's technically *legal* but it an *extremely strange thing to do*, so can you explain why you are doing it?

Comment: These snippets aren't very clear; post a complete working program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You allocate memory

```
int* convex = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
```

then you override pointer

```
convex = check_figure(x_points, y_points);
```

First malloc is never freed. Depending on what you override first pointer with, you might have other memory error.

As pointed out in the comments, if you want to return a value from the function, you can store it in the first allocated int by dereferencing the pointer like :

```
*convex = check_figure(x_points, y_points);
```

Comment: in general: I need to return the pointer to int from the function...am doing it correctly? and what can I do now? Thank you for your answer

Comment: The line `convex = check_figure(x_points, y_points);` doesn't copy data that is pointed to , from the return value into the memory you malloc'd.  It makes `convex` point at the data being pointed to by the return value, instead of pointing at the malloc'd memory. You probably need to store the returned pointer and copy the right number of bytes from it into the malloc'd area.

Comment: There's no problem returning a pointer from a function, if you don't need the first allocation, just don't do it. If you could post the implementation of check_figure, that will help provide a better answer.